# Hiding Get-Action in Web API (mvc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api with the following routes:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
   name: "DefaultGet",
   routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home",  id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

These are two Actions inside a Controller:

```
public class UserController {
   public HttpResponseMessage Get(int id) {}
   public HttpRespnseMesseage GetDetails(int id) {}
}
```

The first route allows me to access the `Get()`-Method by "`/api/User/4711`" The second route allows me to access the `GetDetails()`-Method by "`/api/User/GetDetails/4711`"

This works.

But in addition, the `Get()`-Method can also be called by "`/api/User/Get/4711`" (and is listed in the automaticly generated documentation, too)

How can I make sure, that I can access the Get-Method by "`/api/User/4711`", but not by "`/api/User/Get/4711`"?

Note: I want to keep the default routes and do not want a solution that can only be achieved by removing my default routes and using route attributes instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing something quite strange: you're mixing up deafault RESTful style routing, with action based routing.

With your current configuraton, your second route will match any ULR like `/api/User/XXX/4711` where `XXX` is anything. No matter if `XXX` is `Get` or anything else.

The only thing that you can do to avoid the second route to accept anything is to use route constraints. But, to do so, you must have a fixed set of rules. For example, if you only want to exclude `Get` you can do that with a regex constraint.  But if you don't know the rules, of course, you cannot implement it.

### Recommendation

As the OP finally decided himself, if you're using a RESTful API routing style it's much better to use routing attributes, available since Wep API v2. (In fact there was a Nuget package to support it on previous versions).

Comment: Thanks. You are right. Meanwhile I decided that a (Attribute) Route for the GetDetails of [Route("api/User/{id}/Details")] makes more sense